# Callisto + Pointer Pressed + xmal

Tags: windows-runtime, callisto

I´m using visual studio 2012

Hi I have tried every thing that has come in my mind to try and do this but I can´t find the anwser.

I tried this: `mi1.PointerPressed()`  and it didn't work.
I tried a lot of ways and I din´t find in the callisto help something to explain how I put a command inside of the menuitem.
If some one know and can help me I will thank you so much. xD

```
Flyout flyOut = new Flyout();
flyOut.PlacementTarget = sender as UIElement;
flyOut.Placement = PlacementMode.Bottom;

Menu m = new Menu();
m.MinWidth = 110;
MenuItem mi1 = new MenuItem();
mi1.Text = "Some Option";

MenuItem mi2 = new MenuItem();
mi2.Text = "Another Option Here";

m.Items.Add(mi1);
m.Items.Add(new MenuItemSeparator());
m.Items.Add(mi2);

flyOut.Content = m;

flyOut.IsOpen = true;
```

Hi, How you show it´s one way, but a search more and I send a e-mail to developer and I found a best way using the callisto

```
        private void ShowFlyoutMenu(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
        Flyout flyOut = new Flyout();
        flyOut.PlacementTarget = sender as UIElement;
        flyOut.Placement = PlacementMode.Bottom;


        Menu m = new Menu();
        m.MinWidth = 110;
        MenuItem mi1 = new MenuItem();
        mi1.Text = "TE";
        mi1.Tapped += mi1_Tapped;


        m.Items.Add(mi1);
        m.Items.Add(new MenuItemSeparator());
        m.Items.Add(mi2);

        flyOut.Content = m;

        flyOut.IsOpen = true;

        UpdateLayout();
    }


    private void mi1_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
    /**YOUR CODE*/
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the MenuItem doesn't handle traditional event-based code and you need to implement/use an ICommand implementation with the MenuItem. Two most common ones are [RelayCommand](http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#GalaSoft.MvvmLight/GalaSoft.MvvmLight%20%28NET35%29/Command/RelayCommand.cs) from MVVM Light Toolkit and [DelegateCommand](http://prismwindowsruntime.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Prism.StoreApps/DelegateCommand.cs) from Prism. You can grab the DelegateCommand and its base class code from CodePlex, put it in your project and then you would then do something like this to use the MenuItem:

```
mi1.Command = new DelegateCommand(() => do something ...);
```